# UPDATE trigger issue

Tags: sql-server

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tInsertTaskFromOpportunityReassignment]
ON [dbo].[OpportunityBase]
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    IF UPDATE(owninguser)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @opportunityid uniqueidentifier
        SET @opportunityid = (SELECT
            OpportunityId
        FROM updated)
    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC sp_CreateTaskFromOpportunityAssign @opportunityid
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        INSERT INTO Errors (errornumber, errorseverity, errorstate, errorprocedure, errorline, errormessage)
            VALUES (ERROR_NUMBER(), ERROR_SEVERITY(), ERROR_STATE(), ERROR_PROCEDURE(), ERROR_LINE(), ERROR_MESSAGE())
    END CATCH
    END
END
```

Calling it from my application, I'm getting this back:

> Internal Server Error. This SqlTransaction has completed; it is no
>   longer usable.

Is my syntax above correct? I've used insert triggers before but not update.

Comment: There is no `updated` pseudo-table. There are only `inserted` and `deleted`. For an `UPDATE`, both would be populated. However, in how you're trying to use it, it points to the probability of your existing triggers being broken also - triggers run once per *statement*, not once per row. So the pseudo-tables can contain 0, 1 or *multiple* rows. Which your trigger ignores.

Comment: Ok, thanks. In my application though only 1 row is ever updated at once

Comment: So I would get the @opportunityid from inserted, right?

Comment: Slight detour, your procedure has the sp_ prefix. This is not a good practice. You should use a different prefix, or even better no prefix at all. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must made a ROLLBACK befor you made an INSERT:

```
BEGIN CATCH
    IF (XACT_STATE()) = -1  
    BEGIN  
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;  
    END; 
    INSERT INTO Errors (errornumber, errorseverity, errorstate, errorprocedure, errorline, errormessage)
        VALUES (ERROR_NUMBER(), ERROR_SEVERITY(), ERROR_STATE(), ERROR_PROCEDURE(), ERROR_LINE(), ERROR_MESSAGE())
END CATCH
```